# If a matrix and its determinant given and another matrix also given how to obtain the second matrix determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If the matrix  $$ A =
\pmatrix{row1 \\ row2\\row3}\ and  \left|\begin{array}[ccc]\\ A \end{array}\right|
=10$$

and  matrix

$$  B =
\pmatrix{2row1+row2-row3 \\ 2row3\\5row2}\   \
$$
then find
$$ 
\\\left|\begin{array}[ccc]\\ B \end{array}\right|
= ?$$

I am stuck at this. I know that subtracting a multiple of one row from another row does not change determinate (A). Also, if we do permutation of rows 1 time the sign will be negative, but I do not know if this information is useful here or not.

I need help with this one and after reading StackTD hints B, will be:
$$  B =
\pmatrix{2row1\\2row3\\5row2}\   \
$$
I know the determinant of B will in negative sign because of rows swap, but I couldn't obtain B determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **properties** of determinants:

- the determinant is linear in each row/column;
- a determinant with two identical rows is $0$;
- swapping two rows changes the sign of the determinant.

Now start with linearity and follow up (I write $A_i$ for the $i$th row of the original matrix $A$):
$$\begin{vmatrix}
2A_1+A_2-A_3 \\
2A_3 \\
5A_2
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
2A_1 \\
2A_3 \\
5A_2
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
A_2 \\
2A_3 \\
5A_2
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
-A_3 \\
2A_3 \\
5A_2
\end{vmatrix} = \ldots$$

---

Addition after comment:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\color{blue}{2}A_1 \\
\color{green}{2}A_3 \\
\color{red}{5}A_2
\end{vmatrix}=\color{blue}{2}\cdot\color{green}{2}\cdot\color{red}{5}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}
A_1 \\
\color{purple}{A_3} \\
\color{purple}{A_2}
\end{vmatrix}=\ldots$$

Comment: thanks for explaining that to me, now i updated the subject with matrix B but i couldn't obtain B determinant is that right ?, and how we obtain b determinant  ?

Comment: Linearity also allows you to 'extract' the multiples (in each row!); then notice the swap of two rows. See updated answer.

Comment: thank you again for explaining to me now i have more understading of determinant properties because of your help, and from what you have told me the determinant of B will be -20 right ?

Comment: Almost, $-20$ **times** the determinant $A$, so...?

Comment: so then the determinant of b will be -10 ?

Comment: No, I think you (correctly) found that the determinant of $B$ is $-20$ times the determinant of $A$, but that determinant of $A$ was given and was... So?

Comment: so then we multiply determinant of A which was 10 by -20 we got the result will be -200 and that is the determinant of B is that right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: great and thank you very much